# How to extract unique string pattern in first line with with second line

Tags: shell, grep

I need to perform following steps to extract unique Error codes with 2nd line below thru GREP or by any other command. For some reason, I am unable to get the complete result. Could you please help? Thank You!

```
grep -e '.*[A-Z]-[0-9]*:' -o  -e '.*row.[.0-9]*' test.log
```

1. Need to capture ORA/KUP error code lines with only one line below error code (that starts with 'error processing column......').
2. Notice that for ORA-01843 line, we have two different 2nd lines so we only need first line with 'CON_START_DATE in row 7' and another one for 'error processing column CON_END_DATE in row 66'.
   Any additional line for other rows with same column name is not required. The same goes for other error codes (e.g. ORA-01722). **Basically, Error Code and Error Processing line must be unique**.
3. Must cut any text after row number. E.g., **'error processing column CON_START_DATE in row 6 for datafile test_data1.csv'** will become **'error processing column CON_START_DATE in row 6'**.
4. If there is no second line (starts with 'error processing column......') for any error code then it must be removed.

**test.log:**

```
LOG file opened at 01/01/18 10:10:10

KUP-05004:   Warning: parallel select was not requested.

Field Definitions for table DATA_1_STG
  Record format DELIMITED BY NEWLINE
  Data in file has same endianness as the platform
  Reject rows with all null fields

error processing column CON_START_DATE in row 1 for datafile test_data1.csv
ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected
error processing column SUPPLIER_ID in row 3 for datafile test_data1.csv
ORA-01722: invalid number
error processing column CON_START_DATE in row 6 for datafile test_data1.csv
ORA-01843: not a valid month
error processing column CON_START_DATE in row 7 for datafile test_data1.csv
ORA-01843: not a valid month
error processing column CON_START_DATE in row 8 for datafile test_data1.csv
ORA-01722: invalid number
error processing column CON_START_DATE in row 6 for datafile test_data1.csv
ORA-01843: not a valid month
KUP-04073: record ignored because all referenced fields are null for a record
error processing column CON_END_DATE in row 65 for datafile test_data1.csv
ORA-01843: not a valid month
error processing column CON_END_DATE in row 66 for datafile test_data1.csv
ORA-01843: not a valid month
error processing column CON_END_DATE in row 67 for datafile test_data1.csv
ORA-01843: not a valid month
error processing column CON_START_DATE in row 102 for datafile test_data1.csv
ORA-01843: not a valid month
```

**Required Result:**

```
KUP-05004:   Warning: Intra source concurrency disabled because parallel select was not requested.
error processing column CON_START_DATE in row 1
ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected
error processing column SUPPLIER_ID in row 3
ORA-01722: invalid number
error processing column CON_START_DATE in row 6
ORA-01843: not a valid month
error processing column CON_START_DATE in row 7
KUP-04073: record ignored because all referenced fields are null for a record
error processing column CON_END_DATE in row 65
ORA-01843: not a valid month
error processing column CON_END_DATE in row 66
```

Comment: `awk '/^(ORA|KUP)-[0-9]+:/{c=$0;next}c&&/^error/{e=$0;sub(/ in row .*/,"",e);if(!s[c"\0"e]++){print c;sub(/ for .*/,"");print}c=!c}' test.log` - memory usage is proportional to logfile size in worst case

Comment: Thanks so much jhnc. It is 100% working correctly. 
If you don't mind could you please explain your code at high level. It would be really helpful for my future learning. 

Also, I tried to make a change for (ORA|KUP) with [A-Z] to make error code dynamic but then it did not return anything. Any idea how can I make it work. 

awk '/^[A-Z]-[0-9]+:/{c=$0;next}c&&/^error/{e=$0;sub(/ in row .*/,"",e);if(!s[c"\0"e]++){print c;sub(/ for .*/,"");print}c=!c}' test.log

Comment: I was able to add [A-Z]:   awk '/[A-Z]-[0-9]+:/{c=$0;next}c&&/^error/{e=$0;sub(/ in row .*/,"",e);if(!s[c"\0"e]++){print c;sub(/ for .*/,"");print}c=!c}' test3.log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A fairly simple solution is possible with awk:

```sh
awk -f script.awk test.log
```

**script.awk**

```
/^(ORA|KUP)-[0-9]+:/ {
    # found an error code

    # Store it for later use.
    # Note: If no error processing message has yet been read,
    #       the previously stored code is simply ignored. (4)
    c = $0

    next # don't bother doing anything else with this line
}

# c doubles as the state indicator
# if c is unset, state is: looking for an error code
# if c is set, state is: looking for an error processing message

c && /^error/ {
    # found an error processing message while looking for one

    # store it for later use
    e = $0

    # strip unwanted part
    sub(/ in row .*/,"",e)

    # Indices of array s are unique combinations of code / message.
    # The first time a combination is seen, the value is not yet set
    # (and so s[...] tests false and !s[...] tests true). (2)

    # `++` is an efficient way to do "test and then increment"
    # so that the initially false-ish value tests true next time.

    if ( !s[c"\0"e]++ ) {
        # output the stored error code line (1)
        print c

        # strip unwanted part of message then output (3)(1)
        # by default, sub and print act on $0
        sub(/ for .*/,"")
        print
    }

    # toggle state to looking for an error code
    c=!c
}

# ignore any other lines
```

In the worst case, an array element is added for every pair of code/message lines in the input file. If the file is larger than memory this could be a problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detail explanation and making it as a separate script. This definitely helps.